# If $0<x<1$ then prove that $x^a \leq x < 1$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}, a\geq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If this is true then can somebody please help me to get the proof. Thanks!
I am trying to see the proof of this for all $a\in \mathbb{R}, a\geq 1$.I saw that this is easy inequality to prove if $a\in \mathbb{N}, a\geq 1$.  It follows easily by induction.
 I was trying to do this for $a\in \mathbb{R}, a\geq 1$. Now, I have figured out the proof which I have given below in this thread.

Comment: I know this is true. One can see from the graph.

Comment: prove it by induction

Comment: I'm confused by all the induction proofs. It says $n \in \mathbf{R}$, so induction does not apply.

Comment: Please vote this to reopen. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a proof for this inequality for all $a \geq 1, a\in \mathbb{R}$. Fix $0<x<1$ and 
define a function $f(a) = x^a - x$. Then $f^{\prime}(a) = x^a \ln x-0<0$. Note that $\ln x <0$ for $0<x<1$. So the function is decreasing for $a \geq 1$. That is $f(a) \leq f(1)$ as desired. 
This requires no induction and more powerful than induction.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $0<x<1$ and that $m>n>1 >0$. then $0<1<\frac{1}{x}$. Since $m>n$, there exists $q$ such that $m=n+q$. Note that $(\frac{1}{x})^q>1$ since $\frac{1}{x}>1$.

It is then clear that $(\frac{1}{x})^n<(\frac{1}{x})^n\cdot(\frac{1}{x})^q=(\frac{1}{x})^{n+q}=(\frac{1}{x})^m$.

It follows that $x^m<x^n$.

Since in your case (sorry for my variables) $m=n$ and $n=1$, it follows that

$x^n<x^1<x^0=1$.

Comment: please vote this to reopen

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: @ Andres: There is a reopen link right after the  small paragraph on the top following the headline. Thanks

Comment: One more vote to reopen this. Somebody help.

Comment: I don't have the rep :(

Answer (score 0):

By induction. Multiplied $0<x<1$ by $x$ we have $0<x²<x$. Suppose that $x^{n}\leq x$. Then $$x^{n+1}=xx^{n}\leq xx=x²<x<1.$$

Comment: $n \in \mathbf{R}$ so induction does not apply.

Comment: You are right. I thought that $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The argument needs to be different.

Comment: please vote this to reopen

Answer (score 0):

As $x^a=\mathrm e^{a\ln x}$, proving $x^a<x$ amounts to proving
$$a\ln x\le\ln x\iff a\ge 1$$
since $\ln x <0$.

Comment: $n \in \mathbf{R}$ so induction does not apply.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: @T.S.L.: The O.P. modified his/her question, and I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: please vote this to reopen

Comment: @Mr.MBB: Done, mylord.